# How to use getBlockedUsers using Swifter library for for twitter

Tags: ios, api, twitter, block, swifter

I am creating a light twitter client for iOS using the [Swifter library](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/tree/master/Sources) ... I've been able to use other functions in the library fine, but when I  use the getBlockedUsers function, nothing happens (or I am doing it wrong). This is how i call the function:

```
swifter?.getBlockedUsers(includeEntities: false, skipStatus: true, cursor: "", success: mySuccess as? Swifter.CursorSuccessHandler, failure: failureHandler)
```

and this is what my success handler looks like:

```
let mySuccess: (JSON, String, String) -> Void = { someJson, someString, anotherString in print("some array: ", someJson)
print("some array: ", someString)
print("some array: ", anotherString)}
```

After this....nothing is printed to the console. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify - you are saying you want to block/report user but your are asking about `getBlockedUsers` method for which I see in the source code following description `Returns a collection of user objects that the authenticating user is blocking`. Did you mean `blockUser` method instead?

Comment: @PeterPajchl sorry I meant how do I use the getBlockedUsers function. I updated the question

Comment: One thing I see is that your success handler does not have same signature as in their code. `(JSON, _ previousCursor: String?, _ nextCursor: String?) -> Void` notice that prev/next cursors are optionals.

Comment: @PeterPajchl so should i write it as `let mySuccess: (JSON, String?, String?)...` instead? Sorry, I'm newish to Swift

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @PeterPajchl it still didnt work smh. This is what printed out: `some array:  Optional([])
some array:  Optional("0")
some array:  Optional("0")` any suggestions?